# Inline xslt namespace from parent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

This is actually my inline xslt:

```
<xsl:element name="ns0:LineItems" >
  <xsl:element name="ns0:Response" >
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Response']//*[local-name()='ITEMS']" >
      <xsl:element name="ns0:ITEMS" >
        <xsl:attribute name ="LINEITEMID" >
          <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='LINEITEMID']" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name ="ITM_NUMBER" >
          <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='ITM_NUMBER']" />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

My question is, how can i create the new nodes with the same namespace from the result xml `ns0:elmentname`. When this namespace change to `ns1:elmentname`, I have a problem.

The result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:LineItems xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
  <ns0:Response>
    <ns0:ITEMS LINEITEMID="777" ITM_NUMBER="001000" />
    <ns0:ITEMS LINEITEMID="2" ITM_NUMBER="001055" />
    <ns0:ITEMS LINEITEMID="3" ITM_NUMBER="001020" />
  </ns0:Response>
</ns0:LineItems>
```

My Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <HEADER>
    <ORDER_ID>1234</ORDER_ID>
  </HEADER>
  <E_SALESDOCUMENT>test123</E_SALESDOCUMENT>
  <E_STATUS>AllesToll</E_STATUS>
  <ITEMS>
    <LINEITEMID>777</LINEITEMID>
    <ITM_NUMBER>001000</ITM_NUMBER>
    <MATERIAL>000000000000219701</MATERIAL>
  </ET_ORDER_ITEMS>
  <ET_ORDER_ITEMS>
    <LINEITEMID>2</LINEITEMID>
    <ITM_NUMBER>001055</ITM_NUMBER>
    <MATERIAL>000000000000219702</MATERIAL>
  </ET_ORDER_ITEMS>
  <ET_ORDER_ITEMS>
    <LINEITEMID>3</LINEITEMID>
    <ITM_NUMBER>001020</ITM_NUMBER>
    <MATERIAL>000000000000219703</MATERIAL>
  </ITEMS>
</Response>
```

Comment: You question is not clear to me. "how can i create the new nodes with the same namespace from the result xml" which _same_ namespace?

Comment: And how the input looks like?

Comment: @empo: I am using the xslt, in an inline scripting Functoid. The xml is of the hard-wired mapping and inline-xslt filled. The hard-wired mappings generate an xml like this: `<ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
  <HEADER>
    <ID>7004</ID>
    <bla>data</bla>
  </HEADER>`. The `ns0:` could change to `ns1:`. Because of that i need a dynamic inline xslt namespace prefix.

Comment: The input document has not namespaces. What _problem_ do you have? Do you want a parametric namespace prefix, so that you can change the output from `ns0` to `ns1` on request?

Comment: The problem is that the hard-wired mapping produce a xml with dynamic namespaces and the mapping trough the xslt a inline-xml with static namespaces. I need the same namespace in the xslt-mapping that produced from the BizTalk hard-wired mapping in the result-xml.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with hard-wired mapping and other stuffs. You should simply show the possible inputs you may have and the wanted output. In that case, you may get a meaningful answer.

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX: The fact that the namespace prefix is changed from `ns0:` to `ns1:` doesn't mean that the namespace is changed -- these two prefixes may still be bound to the same namespace. If this is the case, there is no need for you to change the code. You must regard *namespaces*, not *prefixes*. The way to specify the namespace of a newly-created element using `<xsl:element>` is by specifying it as the value of the `namespace` attribute of `<xsl:element>`. If you need to control the prefix, pass it as a parameter (or use a global parameter/variable): `<xsl:element name="{$pref}:someName">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `namespace` of [`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_element.asp) and determine current namespace using XPath `namespace-uri(node-set)` function.
Example:
Suppose we have XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:a="a" xmlns:b="b">
    <a:item>
        <a:name>a</a:name>
    </a:item>
    <b:item>
        <b:name>b</b:name>
    </b:item>
</root>
```

So, we could use this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="a" xmlns:b="b"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a:item | b:item"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:item | b:item">
        <xsl:element namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}" name="element">
            <xsl:value-of select="a:name | b:name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:a="a" xmlns:b="b">
  <element xmlns="a">a</element>
  <element xmlns="b">b</element>
</root>
```

Thereby we construct XML with namespaces dynamically.

Comment: xmlns unfortunately nothing helps me here. Biztalk always uses a namespace prefix in the value for the attribute name.

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX: About what `xmlns` are you talking?

Comment: instead of this `<element xmlns="a">a</element>` i need this `<element name="a:myname">a</element>`

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX: You talking about XSL (`<xsl:element name="a:myname">a</xsl:element>`) or about output XML? If about output XML, may be you mean `<element a:name="myname">a</element>`?